# Get Value from SOAP response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap

I have such a line:

`SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(message, url);`

and response looks:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2013 07:44:39 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <TransactionID soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://somelink"></TransactionID>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soap-env:Fault xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:faultcode>Server</soap-env:faultcode>
   <soap-env:faultstring>Server Error</soap-env:faultstring>
   <soap-env:Detail>
    <soap-env:Status>
     <soap-env:StatusCode>3000</soap-env:StatusCode>
     <soap-env:StatusText>Server Error</soap-env:StatusText>
     <soap-env:Details></soap-env:Details>
    </soap-env:Status>
   </soap-env:Detail>
  </soap-env:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how can i get StatusCode (3000) in String from such a soap response?
i tried `soapResponse.getSOAPBody()....` but all i could get was :status

EDIT:

so i did:

```
  Detail detail = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody().getFault().getDetail();
 Iterator detailEntries = detail.getDetailEntries();
 while (detailEntries.hasNext()) {
     SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) detailEntries.next();
     Iterator val = bodyElement.getChildElements();
     while (val.hasNext()) {
         SOAPBodyElement bodyElement2 = (SOAPBodyElement) val.next();
         String val2 = bodyElement2.getValue();
         logger.debug("The Value is:" + val2);
     }
```

but got class cast exception
       }
Edit2: Solution:

```
soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody().getFault().getDetail().getTextContent().trim().substring(0, 4));
```

Comment: What line is causing the `ClassCastException`? If it's the first line, break it up into single statements in order to trace where it is being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

- Starting from the [`SOAPMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html), you need to call [`SOAPMessage#getSOAPPart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#getSOAPPart%28%29) to obtain a [`SOAPPart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPPart.html).
- By calling [`SOAPPart#getEnvelope()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPPart.html#getEnvelope%28%29) you can obtain the [`SOAPEnvelope`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPEnvelope.html).
- Next you get the [`SOAPBody`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html) using [`SOAPEnvelope#getBody()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPEnvelope.html#getBody%28%29).
- Now you can get the [`SOAPFault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html) by calling [`SOAPBody#getFault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html#getFault%28%29).
- Next, you call [`SOAPFault#getDetail()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html#getDetail%28%29) to obtain the [`Detail`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/Detail.html).
- Using [`Detail#getDetailIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/Detail.html#getDetailEntries%28%29) you can iterate over all of the [`DetailEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/DetailEntry.html)s in the `Detail` object.
- Since the [`DetailEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/DetailEntry.html) interface extends the [`SOAPElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.html) interface, you can get its content by calling [`getChildElements()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.html#getChildElements%28%29); that way you can navigate to the `StatusCode` element inside the `Status` element and get its value.

Comment: Note that you don't need to cast the `DetailEntry` to `SOAPElement` - the methods from `SOAPElement` are automatically available to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
soapResponse.getBody().getFault().getFaultCode()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html#getFaultCode()

```
and iterate on : 

soapResponse.getBody().getFault().getDetailEntries()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/Detail.html#getDetailEntries()