# How can I extract an XML payload from SOAP message with Java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am new to SOAP and need to extract an XML payload from a SOAP message. Our application is contacting a soap service, and the service is returning an XML Document that is embedded within a SOAP message. I need to extract this XML that is within the SOAP body, and save it as a "stand alone" well formed XML document. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything ... I have no SOAP experience and very little XML experience.

Comment: have you even tried searching SO? This might be a good start, or even the answer you are looking for:. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828350/get-value-from-soap-response

Comment: This question is probably too broad. Also, why not use a web service library, like Apache CXF, to handle your SOAP structural needs?

Comment: I cannot use an external library like that.

Comment: Can you provide a sample XML so we can help you with code snippet that solves your problem?